# How to divide a geospatial area into half way points of many lat/lngs

Tags: geospatial, polygon, latitude-longitude

I would like to figure out a way to divide a map into polygons based on the half way positions of lat/long positions.

For example, if there are four lat/long positions on a map (titled "unknown Placemarkers" in the image), I'd like to create four polygons which represent the half way points between the four lat/long positiongs (shown as a yellow line in the image)
[image: four way split example]

Similarly if there were three lat/long positions then the polygons would adjust to have areas which are split by the half way point between the three points.
[image: three way split example]

And the final scenario is that if a lat/lng is surrounded by other polygons the polygon split would be fully enclosed according to the last image.
[image: enclosed four way split]

Comment: Can you describe in more detail where you want the vertices of the polygons to be, how many polygons you want to end up with, and how the geographic coordinate system (latitude/longitude) factors in to those positions (e.g. are the coordinates the only metric you have available)?  If you're trying to be precise, note that it's a bit more complicated than just drawing 2D lines, but that depends on the distance of the lines, really.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance

Comment: Thanks for your comment @mmiron - Essentially I work with a system where a user can select a lat/lng.  Based on that lat/lng the system does a distance based calculation to predefined points (e.g. the "unknown placeholders" in the image) and then selects the predefined point with the least disatnce.  I'd like to pre-generate polygons that represent the area where if a user selected in that area the pre-defined point would be closest.